# loop through non-hidden files matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to loop through non-hidden files in a dir and add them to a cell but for some reason it still preserves the indexing of the hidden files.

Number of non-hidden files in `png_dir_path` = 25

```
listing = dir(png_dirpath);
ecell = {};
for i=1:length(listing)
    name = listing(i).name
    if ~strncmp(name, '.', 1)   % No files starting with '.'
        disp(listing(i).name)
        ecell{i} = fullfile(png_dirpath,listing(i).name);
    end
end
```

When I run the above, I get an `ecell` of size 1x28 but the disp() returns only the hidden filenames. Why is it that when adding the filenames to the cell, it also adds the `'.'`, `'..'` and `'.DS_Store'` ?
Thank you!!

Contents of `png_dirpath`

```
MBP:cartoon_png$ ls
car1.png    car12.png   car15.png   car18.png   car20.png   car23.png   car3.png    car6.png    car9.png
car10.png   car13.png   car16.png   car19.png   car21.png   car24.png   car4.png    car7.png
car11.png   car14.png   car17.png   car2.png    car22.png   car25.png   car5.png    car8.png
```

Output of script:

```
>> load_cartoon

name =

.


name =

..


name =

.DS_Store


name =

car1.png

car1.png

name =

car10.png

car10.png

name =

car11.png

car11.png

name =

car12.png

car12.png

name =

car13.png

car13.png

name =

car14.png

car14.png

name =

car15.png

car15.png

name =

car16.png

car16.png

name =

car17.png

car17.png

name =

car18.png

car18.png

name =

car19.png

car19.png

name =

car2.png

car2.png

name =

car20.png

car20.png

name =

car21.png

car21.png

name =

car22.png

car22.png

name =

car23.png

car23.png

name =

car24.png

car24.png

name =

car25.png

car25.png

name =

car3.png

car3.png

name =

car4.png

car4.png

name =

car5.png

car5.png

name =

car6.png

car6.png

name =

car7.png

car7.png

name =

car8.png

car8.png

name =

car9.png

car9.png
```

As you can see in the above output of the script, the first row in `name` is with hidden files and the 2nd row is without hidden files.

Comment: You get a 1x28 `ecell`, but the hidden files should be missing. Could you please post a sample directory contents and what your script produces?

Comment: You may want to replace `ecell{i} = ...` by `ecell{end+1} = ...` to avoid `ecell` having empty cells corresponding to the hidden files

Comment: Also, what is the shape of `ls`? Is it a row or column?

Comment: @MadPhysicist added output as requested

Comment: @snazziii. That is not very helpful. Could you print out the contents of the variable `ls` before the run and `ecell` after the run?

Comment: Do you really only want the PNG files? If so you could simply your code with something like: `dir([png_dirpath filesep '*.png'])` ... or remove the `filesep` if you already have a separator in your `png_dirpath`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mad Physicist's answer is correct as to why you are having that issue.

However, it looks like there is a much simpler way to just get a listing of PNGs in a directory if that is your end goal.

```
listing = dir(fullfile(png_dirpath,'*.png'));
ecell = {listing.name};
```

No for loop required or directory checking.

Comment: Neat. I didn't know `dir` did globbing, although it makes perfect sense that it would.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is most likely that you are moving the index into `ecell` in lockstep with your index in `ls`. Unless all your hidden files are at the end of the listing, `ecell` will be the same length as `ls`. You can use @LuisMendo's suggestion to remove the lockstep:

```
listing = dir(png_dirpath);
ecell = {};

for item = listing'
    if item.name(1) == '.'
        ecell{end + 1} = fullfile(png_dirpath, item.name);
    end
end
```

Part of the problem is that you are basing your conclusion that the hidden files are still present on the fact that `ecell` is 28 elements long. If you had looked at the contents, you would have realized that your algorithm is almost correct. Debugging is a learned skill. It is very easy to learn **how** to look (you had the right idea with the printouts), but it is very difficult to learn **where** to look.

Comment: Thank you!! Yes, I checked the value of ecell{1} for my code and it is indeed empty. :)